# Identification of the experimental design

Tags: statistics

We have the following structure:

$\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & C & D\\ 
A & C & B & D\\ 
B & A & C & C\\ 
A & A & B & C
\end{bmatrix}$

It is required to tell which design is this CRD,LSD,RBD or factorial design?

I know it can't be LSD as it has same treatments in some row and column. But I am confused between CRD AND RBD.

Comment: Perhaps Randomised Block Design says something about rows *or* columns

Comment: @Henry yes, it says that within each block, all the treatment should occur once.

Comment: And does that happen here?

Comment: @Henry No, and it can't be LSD and factorial. Hence, the given design is an example of CRD. Am I correct?

Comment: That seems a reasonable conclusion

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much.